# Is it possible to cut away transparent areas of Gtk-pixbuf?

Tags: python, gtk, rsvg

I am currently using rsvg in Python to separate Svggroups.
I got it working so that rsvg loads a single group ... alas all the transparent space around that still remains.

Is there a gtk functionallity to cut away all this space?

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in but it's fairly simple to code it (walk over pixels, find the transparent ones). Unfortunately walking over pixels in python is probably slow.